# How to send a Woocommerce order via REST API from a client store to a server / central store

Tags: php, woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, rest

I am doing a practice that consists of sending a Woocommerce order from a client to a server. The client will send the order via REST API as soon as the status changes to completed, at that time, the server (or central store) will receive the order, saving it in its own orders. I have most of the code written, both for the client and the server, but there are things that I don't know how to do.

The truth is that I have performed tests with the Postman software to see if the server listener works and it does.

My doubts regarding the client are if I am correctly sending the entire order.

As for the server I don't know if I am doing the code right in the function that receives the request: I mean my use of json_decode() and if I have to use json_encode() first.

I appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot.

Central store or server code:

```
Plugin Name: Server
Plugin URI: https://www.misitio.com/
Version: 1.0
Author: Yo
Author URI: https://www.misitio.com/
License: GPL2

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

    $woocommerce = new Client(                                      
        'https://misitio.com/',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx862df',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf5037',
        [

        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        ]
    );

       
    add_action('rest_api_init','registrar_mi_endpoint');

    function registrar_mi_endpoint() {
          register_rest_route( 'wc/v3', '/endpoint2/', array(
              'methods' => 'POST',
              'callback' => 'mi_consulta',
              'permission_callback' => function($request){
                  return current_user_can('manage_options');
              },
          ) );
    }

    function mi_consulta(WP_REST_Request $solicitud) {

        $pedido_procesado=json_decode($solicitud,true);
        
        $woocommerce->post('orders', $pedido_procesado);
   
    }
```

Client code

```
Plugin Name: Cliente
Plugin URI:  https://www.misitio.com/
Author: Yo
Author URI: https://www.misitio.com/
Version: 1.0
License: GPL2

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

;
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'funcion1');

function funcion1($order_id) {

    $woocommerce = new Client(
        'https://misitio.com/',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9372',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdfcd',
        ['version' => 'wc/v3',]);

    $sales = $woocommerce->get('orders/'.$order_id);
    $var = json_encode($sales);
    
    $username ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx62df';
    $password ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf5037';

    
    $ch = curl_init("https://misitioservidor.com/wp-json/wc/v3/endpoint2/");

    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if (!curl_errno($server_output)) {
        print_r('it works');
        print_r($status_code);
        exit;
    }else{
        print_r("it doesn't work");
        exit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to write the code for these two plugins. I leave them here in case it helps someone. I have an improved version with more functionalities.

Server Code:

```
Plugin Name: Server
Plugin URI: https://www.misitio.com/
Version: 1.0
Author: Yo
Author URI: https://www.misitio.com/
License: GPL2

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

    $woocommerce = new Client(                                      
        'https://misitio.com/',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx862df',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf5037',
        [

        'version' => 'wc/v3',
        ]
    );

       
    add_action('rest_api_init','registrar_mi_endpoint');

    function registrar_mi_endpoint() {
          register_rest_route( 'wc/v3', '/endpoint2/', array(
              'methods' => 'POST',
              'callback' => 'mi_consulta',
              'permission_callback' => function($request){
                  return current_user_can('manage_options');
              },
          ) );
    }

    function mi_consulta(WP_REST_Request $solicitud) {

        $array = json_decode($solicitud->get_body());       
            
        $data2 = [                                          
            'payment_method' => $array->payment_method,
            'payment_method_title' => $array->payment_method_title,
            'billing' => [
                'first_name' => $array->billing->first_name,    
                'last_name' => $array->billing->last_name,      
                'address_1' => $array->billing->address_1,      
                'address_2' => '',
                'city' => $array->billing->city,                
                'state' => $array->billing->state,              
                'postcode' => $array->billing->postcode,        
                'country' => $array->billing->country,          
                'email' => $array->billing->email,              
                'phone' => $array->billing->phone               
            ],
            'shipping' => [
                'first_name' => $array->shipping->first_name,   
                'last_name' => $array->shipping->last_name,     
                'address_1' => $array->shipping->address_1,     
                'address_2' => '',
                'city' => $array->shipping->city,               
                'state' => $array->shipping->state,             
                'postcode' => $array->shipping->postcode,       
                'country' => $array->shipping->country          
            ],
            'line_items' => [
                [
                    'product_id' => $array->line_items[0]->product_id,
                    'quantity' => $array->line_items[0]->quantity
                ]
            ],
            'shipping_lines' => [
                [
                    'method_id' => $array->shipping_lines[0]->method_id,        
                    'method_title' => $array->shipping_lines[0]->method_title,  
                    'total' => $array->shipping_lines[0]->total                 
                ]
            ]
        ];  
            
        if($woocommerce->post('orders', $data2)){                                   
            print_r("PEDIDO INTRODUCIDO");
        }
   
    }
```

Client Code:

```
Plugin Name: Cliente
Plugin URI:  https://www.misitio.com/
Author: Yo
Author URI: https://www.misitio.com/
Version: 1.0
License: GPL2

require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use Automattic\WooCommerce\Client;
    use Automattic\WooCommerce\HttpClient\HttpClientException;

;
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'funcion1');

function funcion1($order_id) {

    $woocommerce = new Client(
        'https://misitio.com/',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx9372',
        'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxdfcd',
        ['version' => 'wc/v3',]);

    $sales = $woocommerce->get('orders/'.$order_id);
    $var = json_encode($sales);
    
    $username ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx62df';
    $password ='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf5037';

    
    $ch = curl_init("https://misitioservidor.com/wp-json/wc/v3/endpoint2/");

    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");

    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $var);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if (!curl_errno($server_output)) {
        print_r('it works');
        print_r($status_code);
        exit;
    }else{
        print_r("it doesn't work");
        exit;
    }
}
```